# Python help to update Postgres column

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sql-update, where-clause

I have a need to (1) fetch a column from db (2) pass it to api (3) return column from api (4) set returned column in Postgres

I am able to do 1,2 and 3 operation, the script fails on 4.

```
import psycopg2, requests, json

def get_data(): """Get data from  table"""
conn = psycopg2.connect(user="USER",
                    password="PASSWORD",
                    host="HOST",
                    port="PORT",
                    database="DATABASE")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT distinct column1 FROM schema.table1 where column2  is null and column3 = 'RANDOM'  order by column1")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print ("column1 =" ,row[0])

   #Send column1 to API to get column4 as ID
   def send_data_to_post(): """Sending existing data from table to get id"""
   payload = {'column1': row[0]}
   url = 'http://URL'
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
   data = response.json()
   json_str = json.dumps(data)
   resp = json.loads(json_str)
   print (resp['body']['id'],resp['body']['code'])

   #Set id in temp table which was returned by API
   #This below statement fails, error = syntax error at or near "%"
   cur.execute("UPDATE schema.table2 SET column4 = (%(id)s) WHERE column1 = (%(Code)s)")

print ("operation complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your parameters as second argument of [`cursor.execute()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#execute). Right now you only send a prepared statement to the engine and Postgres attempts to read it literally. And because you use named params, pass a dictionary of your values:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE schema.table2 SET column4 = (%(id)s) WHERE column1 = (%(Code)s)",
            {'id': resp['body']['id'], 'Code': resp['body']['code']})
```

Comment: After making changes as suggested, I am not getting an error. However, it was also not updating the database. The missing part was conn.commit(). It's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, add `conn.commit()` or after connecting to PG: `conn.set_session(autocommit=True)`.